# Mobile site problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, wordpress

My website is not working on mobile devices. It loads a different (ugly) version of my site than the responsive one that I designed. There is a link to go to the full website on the mobile version but then it never loads. 
I have an idx plugin that I think is making it do this? Is there a way to disable the mobile version of a plugin? I want the mobile version of my theme, not the plugin.

Any ideas of how to remove this ugly mobile version and make my regular site load on the mobile device? I tested it here: http://www.mattkersley.com/responsive/  and this is what it should look like!

Here is my website: http://jillrea.com